# Code is working without any errors...except it won't display

Tags: php, mysql

The code I used doesn't give me any MySQL errors (which is good)

Except it won't display the results I was looking for (in the url bar it looks like this search.php?departure_label=Dar+Es+Salaam&arrival_label=Zanzibar&txtDate1=03%2F19%2F2012&txtDate2=03%2F20%2F2012&ddlPAxADT=1&ddlPaxCHD=0&ddlPaxINF=0&search=Submit which is what I wanted since it means all of the information was passed through)

It just displays a white screen

Here's the code

```
<?PHP   
$button = $_GET['submit'];
$search = $_GET['search'];
$sfrom = $_GET['departure_label'];
$sfromda = $_GET['txtdate1'];
$sto = $_GET['arrival_label'];
$stoda = $_GET['txtdate2'];
$padt = $_GET['ddlPaxADT'];
$pchd = $_GET['ddlPaxCHD'];
$pinf = $_GET['ddlPaxINF'];


include "connection.php";       
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from search_v where rout_from like'".$sfrom."' and rout_to like'".$sto."' and DATE_FORMAT(date_avialable,'%Y-%m-%d') between'".$sfromda."' and '".$stoda."' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());         
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

$flightid = $runrows['flight_id'];
$aseats = $runrows['seats_avialable'];
$todate = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['to_date']));
$date = strftime("%b %d, %Y %l:%M %p" ,strtotime($runrows['date_avialable']));
$from = $runrows['rout_from'];
$to = $runrows['rout_to'];
$acost = $runrows['adult_cost'];
$ccost = $runrows['child_cost'];
$cur = $runrows['currency'];
$oth = $runrows['other_cost'];

echo "";                
?>
<li class="item clearfix"> <span
 id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_rptmain_lblFromt_0">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <thead><tr>
        <th class="price">Price</th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
        <th>Depart</th>
        <th>Arrive</th>
      </tr>
      </thead><tfoot> <tr>
        <td><a class="more" href="#">Full
Details</a></td>
        <td colspan="6">
        <div class="select-wrap">
        <p class="seats"><strong><?php echo $aseats; ?></strong> <span>seats
left</span> <em>at this price</em></p>
        <button class="btn-select" type="button"
 onclick='return ray.ajax("#");'>Select Flight</button></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tfoot><tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="price" rowspan="2"><a
 style="font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none;"
 herf="#" onclick='return ray.ajax("#");'><span
 style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $totalcost; ?></span><span
 style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; font-weight: normal;">per
adult</span><span
 style="font-size: 12px; margin-top: 2px; display: block; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: center; font-weight: normal;">(with fees)</span></a></td>
          <td><?php echo $from; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $to ?></td>
          <td style="padding-right: 2px;">4:05 PM</td>
          <td>7:05 PM</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </span> <a
 id="cntntMiddle_ctl01_rptmain_lblResultDetails1_0" title="1"
 href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cntntMiddle$ctl01$rptmain$ctl00$lblResultDetails1','')"
 style="color: Black;"></a><a class="close"
 href="#">Close</a>
    <div class="info clearfix">
    <div class="info clearfix">
    <h4>Departing Flight</h4>
    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li>
        <h5><?php echo $from; ?> to <?php echo $to; ?> <?php echo $date; ?></h5>
        <ul>
          <li>&nbsp;</li>
          <li><strong>Flight #</strong> - <?php echo $flightid; ?></li>
          <li><strong>Departure Time – </strong>
6:05 PM</li>
<li><strong>Arrival Time</strong> - 5:05 PM</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
      <ul>
        <li style="padding-top: 5px;"><span
 style="color: rgb(212, 22, 13); font-weight: bold; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none;">
Fare Breakdown</span> </li>
      </ul>
      <table class="more">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Passenger</th>
            <th>Fare</th>
            <th> Taxes and Fees</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Total Cost</th>
          </tr>
        </tbody><tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Adult</td>
            <td
 style="color: rgb(100, 100, 100); font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $acost; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $oth; ?></td>
            <td id="paxAdtTd">1</td>
            <td><?php echo $totaladult; ?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Cost of Sale(<?php echo $cur; ?>)</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td
 style="color: rgb(100, 100, 100); font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"><?php echo $totaladult; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br />
      <span style="font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
*Additional airline fees for baggage may apply</span>
      <div class="select-wrap">
      <p class="seats"><strong><?php echo $aseats; ?></strong> <span>seats
left</span> <em>at this price</em></p>
      <button class="btn-select" type="button"
 onclick='return ray.ajax("https://res.website.com/checkout.aspx?recommendation=1&subset=1&supplier=53&page=flightconfirm",1,this);'>Select
Flight</button></div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Turn on display of errors and maximum error reporting level.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Yeah they're both turned on. Just to check, I deleted a quote from the echo to see if mysql would catch it and it did.

Comment: Are you sure, your resultset of query is not empty?

Comment: There is data, its just not displaying it

Comment: what are the item and clearfix classes in CSS?

Comment: Would that explain the lack of displayed results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from search_v where rout_from like %'".$sfrom."'% and rout_to like %'".$sto."'% and DATE_FORMAT(date_avialable,'%Y-%m-%d') between'".$sfromda."' and '".$stoda."' LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
```

there were two (logical?) errors, with LIKE function, you didn't use a wildcard `%` key, and in next LIKE occurance, for `$sto` you didn't provide a blankspace.

Comment: Would the query still work if I didnt use the like function and used a '=' function instead?

Comment: depends on how you want to search. I would suggest using a regexp instead of `LIKE`

Comment: @MohamedYusuf Try using a print_r( $runrows ); in your while loop. Please inform with/about the output!

Comment: Your first post was actually constructive. It alteast gave an error instead of a blank page lol it said this You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Dar Es Salaam' and rout_to like 'Zanzibar' and DATE_FORMAT(date_avialable,'%Y-%' at line 1

Comment: I will suggest you to use variables as `{$sto}` instead of using a concatenation. It helps a lot!